# Writing Test Cases with Jest in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to write Jest Test case for the below code.I am new to writing test.
Can anyone give me a heads up. I have jest-enzyme and jest-cli running and i want to write in pure jest.

Below is the code i am trying to write about so apart from DOM check i need to check what values are coming or do i need to write UT for other things also?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Message extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


    }

    render() {
        let i =1;
        return(
        <div className="message-main-div">
        <li className={`chat ${this.props.user === this.props.chat.username ? "right" : "left"}`}>
        <div className="chat-timestamp">{this.props.chat.timestamp}</div>
        {this.props.user !== this.props.chat.username && <img className="avatar-img" src={this.props.chat.img} alt={`${this.props.chat.username}'s profile pic`} />}
        <div className="chat-text"><p>{this.props.chat.content}</p></div>
        </li>
        {this.props.user != this.props.chat.username &&
            this.props.chat.buttons.map((button) => {
                 return <div key={i++} className="buttons-wrapper-div"><button className="response-button"onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, button)}>{button}</button></div>
            })
        }
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Message;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple things you can check in the unit test. You can use code-[coverage](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#collectcoverage-boolean) functionality of jest to figure out, which lines and branches of your code are actually covered by tests.

This could be a start (there might be some required props for your component missing):

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'

import Message from '../components/Message'

describe('The Message component', () => {
  it('should render li.chat.left when props.user !== props.chat.username', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Message user='foo' chat={{username: 'bar', buttons: []}} />)
    expect(wrapper.find('li.chat.left').length).toEqual(1)
    expect(wrapper.find('li.chat.right').length).toEqual(0)
  })

  it('should render li.chat.right when props.user === props.chat.username', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Message user='foo' chat={{username: 'foo', buttons: []}} />)
    expect(wrapper.find('li.chat.left').length).toEqual(0)
    expect(wrapper.find('li.chat.right').length).toEqual(1)
  })

  it('should render the chat.timestamp prop as .chat-timestamp', () => {
     const wrapper = shallow(<Message chat={{timestamp: '1234', buttons: []}} />)
     expect(wrapper.find('.chat-timestamp').text()).toEqual('1234')
  )}

})
```